# gradle command for Maven equivalent

Tags: maven, gradlew

What is the gradlew command which is equivalent to below maven command. I am trying to convert the script that uses maven commands to gradle.

```
mvn -D maven.repo.local=/gitlab-builder -D skipTests -P ${1} --also-make --also-make-dependents package
```

thanks